# Since the new execute update in Bedrock, how do I fix the failed to execute fill as username?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

This command is for a haunted house I am making for my friends and I wanted to use this command for a flashlight on Minecraft.

I don't know what is wrong:

```
/execute as @p at @s run fill ~5~2~-5 ~-5~-2~5 air replace light_block
```

Comment: Missing space between "~X"?

Comment: Your command will fail if there are no light blocks within the selected area.

Answer (score 1):

If the output is *Failed to execute 'fill' as [username]*, then there are no light blocks around the area. If you are trying to **add** light blocks to replace air, then you need to switch the *light_block* and *air* around, and add a tag to give a light level to the block, like this:

```
/execute as @p at @s run fill ~5~2~-5 ~-5~-2~5 light block["block_light_level"=12] replace air
```

However, if you start moving, the light blocks will stay there, so you should use another command block to deal with this.

1. Place a **repeating, always active** command block with this command:

   `/execute as @p at @s run fill ~5~3~-5 ~-5~-3~5 air replace light_block`
2. Then, place a **chain, always active** command block coming out of it with this command:

   `/execute as @p at @s run fill ~4~2~-4 ~-4~-2~4 light_block["block_light_level"=12] replace air`

The first command removes all light blocks within a large cube around the player, while the second command adds light blocks with a light level of 12 within a cube one block smaller on each side.

If you want multiple players to have the flashlight, replace the `@p` with `@a`.